# Importing .sql-File into Database without PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to import a .sql-File into a database for TYPO3 , but i dont have the login to the phpmyadmin, because our boss is away for a few days.

Is this possible?

I have the login data for the ftp, the name of the db, host, an user and password for this database.

Comment: Yes, you can install and use the mysql command line client, or any other GUI client as long as the DB name, host, username and password are correct and the host your are connecting from is allowed access via those credentials.

Answer (score 1):

On the  command line...

```
 mysql -u<USERNAME> -p<PASSWORD> <DATABASE> < /path/to/my.sql
```

For example:

```
 mysql -unshar -pmypass mydatabase < /home/nshar/my.sql
```